# Flutter - Add orElse to FirstWhere

Tags: flutter, dart

I´m tring to add [orElse](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.0/dart-async/Stream/firstWhere.html) to this code

```
location
     .firstWhere(
         (calle) => calle["types"][0].toString() == "route")['long_name']
     ).toString();
```

Anybody know what is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.0/dart-async/Stream/firstWhere.html) function prototype is

```dart
Future<T> firstWhere (bool test(T element), { T orElse() })
```

which means that `orElse` is a named parameter which is a function returning a `T` (a `calle` in your case).

So you should write it this way :

```dart
location
    .firstWhere(
        (calle) => calle["types"][0].toString() == "route"),
        orElse: () => null
    )['long_name'] ?? '';
.toString();
```

Comment: Doesn´t work. I want when "route" exist put [long_name]. It does´t exist put ' '.

Comment: Answer updated. You are looking for `??` operator which basically means `if null`

Comment: Anyway, if exist 'route' element return "Tried calling: []("long_name"). The method '[]' was called on null."

Comment: You must ensure that `calle["types"]` is a `List` and is not null before looking for its `[0]` element

Comment: In some cases [ ] doesn´t exists, so return this error.

Comment: Well you can try to compose with the if null `??` operator to prevent error from triggering.

Comment: Can you put a example with this location.firstWhere(
            ((calle) => calle["types"][0].toString() == "route"),
            orElse: () => null)
        ['long_name'].toString() ??
        '';